# how to stop assigning derived class object to base class pointer

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have four classes:

```
class Base
{
    public void printf()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am from base !!!");
    }
}

class DerivedA : Base
{
    public void printf()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am from derived A !!!");
    }
}

class DerivedB : Base
{
    public void printf()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am from derived B !!!");
    }
}

class testProgram
{
    public void print(Base baseClass)
    {
        baseClass.printf();
    }
}
```

my aim is when I execute following code, in line 4 it must give me compile error.

```
testProgram tP = new testProgram();
tP.print(baseClass);
tP.print(derivedA);
tP.print(derivedB);
```

What changes I need to do?

Comment: What distinguishes it from the 3rd line?

Comment: Don't inherit Base. Problem solved. Give more information if you want more assistance, though it does seem you have a design problem if a derived class cannot be substituted for your base.

Comment: Include the compiler error please. "It gave me an error" is not helpful.

Comment: @Gutblender From what I understand, the code doesn't give an error, but he wants it to. Why? No idea.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I misread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that in general at compile time (easy to do at run time).

You can special case particular classes by providing explicit overloaded versions:

```
public void print(Base baseClass)...

[ObsoleteAttribute("This method not supported for DerivedB.", true)] 
public void print(DerivedB baseClass) {}
```

Note: this only helpful if you have type at compile time:

```
print(new DerivedB()); // error
print((Base)new DerivedB()); // success
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent invoking the method with an instance of `DerivedB` that's cast to `Base`.